# how to reload every tab of browser which have open our webpages

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

gmail use some functionality by which they reload all tabs for the login. that means if we open login form of gmail in different different tabs. then login in single tab gmail automatically reload all the pages and redirect to mail page . how it is possible ?

is there any particular frame work to implement this?

Comment: that means server push functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple possibilities, like:

```
- Websockets
- Push notifications
- Long polling
```

I won't recommend you any tools for that, as this may change over time, you will find plenty of resources on Google.

Comment: I think you mean "long polling".

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo :) Thank you, @Aaron.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Chrome browser, then I would suggest you to add an extension like "Reload All Tabs". Once you added this extension you can easily reload all the open tabs by clicking the icon of the extension.

Comment: This is not a way. how i can add that extension on client's machine?